# Cannot install pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow

I am having issues with installing `pyarrow` and any package that relies on it (e.g., `pandas-gbq`). I tried various combinations of modules (including different cmake versions), but always get an error that the wheel fails to build. Please see output below from pip install pyarrow.

Any suggestions? This is a `CentOS` cluster that I'm working on. Thanks!

Edit: Full output below

````
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/custom/python/wheelhouse/gentoo/sse3, /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/custom/python/wheelhouse/gentoo/generic, /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/custom/python/wheelhouse/generic
Collecting pyarrow
  Using cached pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/68/d3410e975bebbf5be00c1238d0418345d8ec5d88b7a6c102211a1c967edd/pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyarrow/) (requires-python:>=3.7): Requested pyarrow from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/68/d3410e975bebbf5be00c1238d0418345d8ec5d88b7a6c102211a1c967edd/pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz has inconsistent version: expected '12.0.1', but metadata has '12.0.0'
  Using cached pyarrow-12.0.0.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.6 in /global/home/pc_mzoican/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.22.2+computecanada)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [335 lines of output]
      <string>:34: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute_docstrings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_generated_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/acero.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/benchmark.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/cffi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/compute.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/csv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/cuda.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/feather.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/filesystem.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/flight.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/fs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/hdfs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/ipc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/jvm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/orc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/pandas_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/substrait.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      copying pyarrow/interchange/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      copying pyarrow/interchange/buffer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      copying pyarrow/interchange/column.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      copying pyarrow/interchange/dataframe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      copying pyarrow/interchange/from_dataframe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/interchange
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/parquet
      copying pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/parquet
      copying pyarrow/parquet/core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/parquet
      copying pyarrow/parquet/encryption.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/parquet
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/arrow_16597.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/arrow_7980.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/pandas_examples.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/pandas_threaded_import.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/read_record_batch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/strategies.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_acero.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_adhoc_memory_leak.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_deprecations.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_exec_plan.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_extension_type.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_feather.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/vendored
      copying pyarrow/vendored/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/vendored
      copying pyarrow/vendored/docscrape.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/vendored
      copying pyarrow/vendored/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/vendored
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/interchange
      copying pyarrow/tests/interchange/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/interchange
      copying pyarrow/tests/interchange/test_interchange_spec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/interchange
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/encryption.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_compliant_nested_type.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_data_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_datetime.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_encryption.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_metadata.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_file.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_writer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      running egg_info
      writing pyarrow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
      reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '../LICENSE.txt'
      warning: no files found matching '../NOTICE.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
      writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying pyarrow/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_acero.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_acero.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_csv.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_csv.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_cuda.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_cuda.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset_orc.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset_parquet.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_feather.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_flight.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_fs.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_fs.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_gcsfs.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_hdfs.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_hdfsio.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_json.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_orc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_orc.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet_encryption.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet_encryption.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_s3fs.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_substrait.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/array.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/benchmark.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/builder.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/compat.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/config.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/error.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/gandiva.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/io.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/ipc.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/lib.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/lib.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/memory.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/pandas-shim.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/public-api.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/scalar.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/table.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/tensor.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/types.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/common.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_acero.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset_parquet.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_feather.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_flight.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_fs.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_python.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_substrait.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libgandiva.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/tests/bound_function_visit_strings.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/extensions.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/CMakeLists.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/arrow_to_pandas.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/arrow_to_pandas.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/arrow_to_python_internal.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/benchmark.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/benchmark.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/common.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/common.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/csv.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/csv.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/datetime.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/datetime.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/decimal.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/decimal.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/deserialize.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/deserialize.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/extension_type.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/extension_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/filesystem.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/filesystem.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/flight.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/flight.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/gdb.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/gdb.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/helpers.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/helpers.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/inference.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/inference.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/init.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/init.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/io.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/io.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/ipc.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/ipc.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/iterators.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_convert.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_convert.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_internal.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_interop.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_to_arrow.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/numpy_to_arrow.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/parquet_encryption.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/parquet_encryption.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/pch.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/platform.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/pyarrow.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/pyarrow.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/pyarrow_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/pyarrow_lib.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/python_test.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/python_test.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/python_to_arrow.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/python_to_arrow.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/serialize.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/serialize.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/type_traits.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/udf.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/udf.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/visibility.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/feather
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/feather/v0.17.0.version.2-compression.lz4.feather -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/feather
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.orc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.jsn.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.orc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      running build_ext
      creating /tmp/pip-install-s9hv1mcn/pyarrow_9d09c8675c4f4ea39575092bf21e4e86/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      -- Running cmake for PyArrow
      cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/pip-install-s9hv1mcn/pyarrow_9d09c8675c4f4ea39575092bf21e4e86/build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyarrow -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/sse3/Core/python/3.9.6/bin/python3.9 -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/sse3/Core/python/3.9.6/bin/python3.9 -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_SUBSTRAIT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ACERO=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GCS=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_CYTHON_CPP=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-s9hv1mcn/pyarrow_9d09c8675c4f4ea39575092bf21e4e86
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
      -- Check for working C compiler: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/Core/gcccore/9.3.0/bin/cc
      -- Check for working C compiler: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/Core/gcccore/9.3.0/bin/cc -- works
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/Core/gcccore/9.3.0/bin/c++
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/Core/gcccore/9.3.0/bin/c++ -- works
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Using ccache: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/bin/ccache
      -- System processor: x86_64
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2 - Success
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX2
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX2 - Success
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX512
      -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX512 - Success
      -- Arrow build warning level: PRODUCTION
      -- Using hard-wired gold linker (version 1.16)
      -- Build Type: RELEASE
      -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:  -Wall -fno-semantic-interposition -msse4.2  -fdiagnostics-color=always  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
      -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:  -Wno-noexcept-type  -Wall -fno-semantic-interposition -msse4.2  -fdiagnostics-color=always  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
      -- Generator: Unix Makefiles
      -- Build output directory: /tmp/pip-install-s9hv1mcn/pyarrow_9d09c8675c4f4ea39575092bf21e4e86/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/release
      -- Found Python3: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/sse3/Core/python/3.9.6/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy
      -- Found Python3Alt: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/sse3/Core/python/3.9.6/bin/python3.9
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:261 (find_package):
        By not providing "FindArrow.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
        asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow", but
        CMake did not find one.

        Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow" with any of
        the following names:

          ArrowConfig.cmake
          arrow-config.cmake

        Add the installation prefix of "Arrow" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
        "Arrow_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Arrow"
        provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
        installed.


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/tmp/pip-install-s9hv1mcn/pyarrow_9d09c8675c4f4ea39575092bf21e4e86/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      error: command '/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````

Comment: Can you share the full output of whatever pip command you're running, as well as your CentOS version? Pre-built wheels should be available.

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and then try installing `pyarrow`.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Hello @MariusZoican, as @amoeba said, can you specify the current CentOS version that you use?, try to write `cat /etc/os-release` inside the host in order to check the current CentOS distrubtion that you are provide a more clear solution. Seems to me that the problem coming from the python package `Cython`, right now the version `3.0.0` it is breaking many dependant packages.

Comment: Here is my CentOS version:

```NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"```

Comment: The error is because it cannot find an Arrow C++ installation, which is a requirement when building pyarrow from source. But the main question is why pip is downloading a source distribution, and not a pre-built wheel. Pyarrow provides manylinux2014 wheels, which I thought should be compatible with CentOS 7.

Comment: Apparently the CPU on the cluster is old and does not support AVX instruction set. Any way around this, perhaps a flag when installing the package?

Comment: You need to follow the instructions for building from source: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#building-on-linux-and-macos but it's not an easy task.